# how to properly handle firebase realtime database listeners with useEffect?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

```
const Messages = (props) => {
      const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
      const { currentChannel, currentUser } = props;
      const messagesRef = firebase.database().ref("messages");
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (currentChannel && currentUser) {
          const channel = currentChannel.currentChannel;
          let loadedMessages = [];
          messagesRef.child(channel.id).on("child_added", (snap) => {
            loadedMessages.push(snap.val());
          });
          setMessages(loadedMessages);
        }
    
        return () => messagesRef.off();
      }, [currentChannel, currentUser, messagesRef]);
    
      const displayMessages = (messages) =>
        messages.length > 0 &&
        messages.map((message) => (
          <Message key={message.timestamp} message={message} user={currentUser} />
        ));
    
      return (
        <>
          <MessagesHeader />
          <Segment>
            <Comment.Group className="messages">
              {displayMessages(messages)}
            </Comment.Group>
          </Segment>
          <MessageForm
            messagesRef={messagesRef}
            currentChannel={currentChannel}
            currentUser={currentUser}
          />
        </>
      );
    };
```

> Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a
> component calls `setState` inside `useEffect`, but `useEffect` either
> doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on
> every render.

How to prevent this infinite loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you render, you're creating a new `messagesRef` object. It may be dealing with the same spot in the database, but it's a new object. Since `messageRef` changed, your effect will rerun and that effect will call `setMessages` with a brand new array each time. Since you set state, the component rerenders, and the loop repeats.

Most of the time, i would recommend having the database ref only exist inside your `useEffect`, and then removing it from the dependency array. However, it looks like you need to pass the ref as a prop to `MessageForm`, so that won't work here. Instead, you need to make sure that you only create the database ref once. `useMemo` is one way to do this:

```
const messagesRef = useMemo(() => {
  return firebase.database().ref("messages");
}, []);
```